# get wordpress post content in google map infowindow

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, google-maps

I have created a googlemaps based branches page, in which the places are created through a custom post type and a google map Advanced Custom Fields object.

the only problem is:
if I want to have the content of the post inside the infoWindow (to show the location's details etc.)
and the content have more then one line - the code breaks...

**for example**

this will work fine:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, id malorum numquam per
```

but this will break:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
id malorum numquam per
```

this is the code for getting the location content:

```
        var locations = [<?php while( $wp_query->have_posts() ){
        $wp_query->the_post();
        $location = get_field('google_map'); 
        ?>
        //acf location's details array
        ['<h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1><h2><?php the_field('branch_name'); ?></h2><div id=<?php echo $post->ID; ?>><?php echo $post->post_content; ?></div>', 
        <?php echo $location['lat']; ?>, <?php echo $location['lng'];?>, <?php $NUM++ ?>],
        <?php } ?> ];
```

and this is how I get it to the infowindow:

```
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
                infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
                for (var j = 0; j < markers.length; j++) {
                markers[j].setIcon("<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/mapmarker.png");
            }
            marker.setIcon("<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/mapmarker-active.png");
        };
    })(marker, i));
```

here is a codeshare link to the full template's code:
http://www.codeshare.io/zaj6n

Comment: What is it give if you alert your `locations` ?

Comment: it's kind of the same problem.
when I alert it and the post content has only one line - it alert the content ok when clicking on the marker.
but - if the content has 2 lines or more - it breaks and the map doesn't show.
I get "SyntaxError: unterminated string literal" in the Firebug...

Comment: Is it still breaking if you make two array... 1 is for `latlng` and other is for `info window content` ..

Comment: tried it now - still breaks...

Comment: I don't have a live demo and I can't share the site itself... :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `json_encode` to print strings which contain linebreaks(or characters that would be problematic in JS, e.g. quotes):

```
echo json_encode($post->post_content);
```

To avoid the double-quotes created by json_encode populate a PHP-array with the desired values and print the entire array by using `json_encode`:

(not tested)

```
<?php 
  $locations=array();
  while( $wp_query->have_posts() ){
        $wp_query->the_post();
        $location = get_field('google_map');
        $locations[]=array(the_title('<h1>','</h1>',false).
                             '<h2>'.get_field('branch_name').'</h2>'.
                             '<div id="'.$post->ID.'">'.$post->post_content.'</div>',
                           $location['lat'],
                           $location['lng'],
                           $NUM++
                           ); 
  }
  echo "\nvar locations=".json_encode($locations).";\n";

?>
```

Comment: How do I get rid of the " " before and after the content it echos?

Comment: can you please explain this method? I didn't really get it :/

Comment: `json_encode` encodes each type of variable(strings,numbers,objects,booleans), also arrays. The result will be a JSON, suitable to be used in Javascript (JSON is the abbreviation for **J**ava**S**cript **O**bject **N**otation)